# IF Statement runs even if the return is false

Tags: jquery, if-statement, slide

I am trying to build my own image slideshow, so the code will look into a specific div and if all the images are hidden it should fadeToggle the first image in the div and then re-fires the function again. The problem i am facing is that i check to see if the number of img:hidden is equal img.length inside that div (which is the starting faze), if its true then the code should fadeToggle the first image img:first and it should never run again because the next time this function runs img:hidden != imglength as one of the images is visible. BUT it keeps running. Please look at the code below.

Thanks

```
<div class="mainSlide">
<img src="img/1.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img src="img/2.jpg" style="display:none;" />
<img src="img/3.jpg" style="display:none;" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

slideShow();

function slideShow() {
    $allSlides = $('div.mainSlide img').length;
    $hiddenSlides = $('div.mainSlide img:hidden').length;

    if ($hiddenSlides == $allSlides) {
        $('div.mainSlide img:first').fadeToggle('slow').delay(5000);
    }
    slideShow();
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: They won't be immediately `:hidden` when you call `.fadeToggle`, otherwise you wouldn't see any animation at all. You also have infinite recursion with this.

Comment: but i even increased the delay to 15000 to give enough time for images to fade in / out. yet it will still fadeToggle, i tested with a command button after the fade in and it showed $hiddenSlides = 2 and $allSlides = 3 but when the function ran again it entered the if statement

Comment: What do you think `.delay` does? For it to defer `.fadeToggle`, it must be called before it. You have infinite recursion and the if statement returns true until stack overflow.

Comment: how about if i changed it to: $('div.mainSlide img:first').fadeToggle('slow').delay(5000).css('display','block');

Comment: there are many many tutorials on how to create a slideshow, based on your understanding of how your code works.... you should start with some tutorials first

Comment: @Maz please read [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) :x `.delay` does not work like you think it does.

Comment: i been trying to look for some, can you recommend some links? all i get on google are plugins

Comment: not sure why you have problems , a simple search turned up lots of results....  [Google result link](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=jquery+slideshow+tutorial)

Comment: @Esailija: Correction: the function returns nothing, which is why you get a stack overflow.

Comment: @Maz: Esailifa gave you a link to the actual documentation in his comment. Please read the documentation for tools that you use, instead of just trying to guess how they work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the the callback?

```
function slideShow() {
  $allSlides = $('div.mainSlide img').length;
  $hiddenSlides = $('div.mainSlide img:hidden').length;

  if ($hiddenSlides == $allSlides) {
    $('div.mainSlide img:first').fadeToggle('slow', function() {
      slideShow();
    });
  }
}
```